# The analog of the function np.isclose() in Python

Tags: r, seq

For R, tell me the analog of the function `np.isclose()` in `Python`?
This function solves the problem of storing floating point numbers in `Python`.
I have the analog problem in R with finding some float numbers in the vector with two signs after the dot:

```r
x <- 153.14
y <- 333.14
z <- seq(x, y, by=0.01)

300.03 %in% z
[1] TRUE
300.04 %in% z  
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: [`near`](https://rdrr.io/cran/dplyr/man/near.html)?
"This is a safe way of comparing if two vectors of floating point numbers are (pairwise) equal. This is safer than using ==, because it has a built in tolerance"

Comment: By default the tolerance in `near` is very low, so doing `any(near(303.4, z, tolerance = 0.01))` would be the equivalent of `303.4 %in% z` with a tolerance of 0.1

Comment: Great, thanks for help. In my version "R", I cut "tolerance" by "tol", and that won. `any(near(303.04, z,  tol = 0.01))`